# Sqlplus 'insufficient privileges' while trying to grant sysdba to user

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I've got a VirtualBox Oracle Linux Image containing an Oracle DB and have used Oracle SQL Developer to connect to that database.

I used the already existing credentials:

```
user: system
password: oracle
```

When I list the user's roles, this is what I receive:
[image]

My problem is, I can't seem to have enough privileges to assign the **SYSDBA** privilege to another user I've created. In the Linux terminal, I executed the following queries using `sqlplus`:

```
create user mmateas identified by passwd;
grant sysdba to mmateas;
```

User **mmateas** has been successfully created, but the second query outputs the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: Insufficient privileges
```

My question is, why does such thing happen? Is there a possibility for **SYSTEM** to not have enough privileges in order to grant **SYSDBA** to my new user?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/administering-user-accounts-and-security.html#GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5) says that `SYS` has `SYSDBA`. Are you sure you want to grant such a powerful privilege at all? This isn't really on-topc for this site; and why have you tagged this with SQL Developer and SQL\*Plus - it's nothing to do with which client you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a problem with the actual user **SYSTEM**.

The [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_2111.htm) states the following:

> V$PWFILE_USERS lists all users in the password file, and indicates whether the user has been granted the SYSDBA, SYSOPER, and SYSASM privileges.

So the only thing I should have done, in order to find out if **SYSTEM** has the **SYSDBA** privilege granted, was to `SELECT` the entries that have `SYSDBA=TRUE`. User **SYSTEM** doesn't seem to have it, but **SYS** has it.

Connecting using the following command in the terminal:

```
sqlplus SYS as SYSDBA
```

and inserting "oracle" as the password, seemed to have fixed the job.